# Where does redux-form's `meta : { touched, error }` live? Could I access it when not contained by renderField scope?

Tags: javascript, jsx, redux-form

The [redux-form documentation](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/examples/submitvalidation/) advises me to render my input and submit-validation errors like this.

```
const renderField = ({ input, placeholder, className, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
      <div>
        <input {...input} className={className} placeholder={placeholder} type={type}/>
        {touched && error && <span><font color="red">{error}</font></span>}
      </div>
  )
```

Inside `render(){return(<form>    </form>)}` you are then supposed to create your inputs like this (note `component={renderField}` in the next code line):

```
<Field type="password" placeholder="password" className="form-control" component={renderField} name="password"/>
```

I wanted to customize this in order to fit it better into my own work. But I cannot seem to find a way to target touched and error unless I place the component in renderField, I guess I am still missing some vital knowledge. Where are these `meta: {touched, error}` properties going exactly and if I can access them somewhere?

Below is my entire container file for your reference.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from "redux-form"
import Title from "../components/Title.js"

const renderField = ({ input, placeholder, className, type, meta: { touched, error } }) => (
      <div className={"" + touched && error && "input_error_border"}>
        <input {...input} className={className} placeholder={placeholder} type={type}/>
        {touched && error && <span><font color="red">{error}</font></span>}
      </div>
)

class RegisterForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
    }
    is_registered(){
        if(this.props.user.server && this.props.user.insert){
            return (<div>
                    <p>Thank you for registering {this.props.user.first_name}</p>
                    <p>You will recieve an email with further instructions shortly.</p>
                </div>)
        }else{
            return <div></div>
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit } className="box-sizing mx-auto max_vertical_form_400">
                    <Title innerH="Register New User"/>
                    <div className="input-group-btn">
                        {this.is_registered()}
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <Field type="text" placeholder="first name" className="form-control" component={renderField} name="first_name" />
                        <Field type="text" placeholder="last name" className="form-control" component={renderField} name="last_name" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <Field type="text" placeholder="email" className="form-control" component={renderField} name="email"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <Field type="text" placeholder="company" className="form-control" component={renderField} name="company"/>
                        <Field type="text" placeholder="department" className="form-control" component={renderField} name="department"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <Field type="password" placeholder="password" className="form-control" component={renderField} name="password"/>
                        <Field type="password" placeholder="repeat password" className="form-control" component={renderField} name="password_repeated"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    {/* <RegisterFormContainer />
                    <ThemeContainer /> */}
            </form>
        );
    }
}
function validate(values){
    const errors= {};
    if(!values.password) errors.password = "missing password";
    if (!values.email) {
        errors.email = 'Required'
    } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)) {
        errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
    }
    return errors;
}

RegisterForm = reduxForm({
    form: "register_user_form",
    validate
})(RegisterForm)

function mapStateToProps({ user }) {
    return { user };
}

export default RegisterForm = connect(mapStateToProps, null)(RegisterForm)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use redux-form [selectors](https://redux-form.com/7.3.0/docs/api/selectors.md/), specifically `getFormMeta` to know which fields are `dirty` or `touched` and `getFormSyncErrors` to know the fields having errors.

In your code, you need to change to import the selectors

```
import { getFormMeta, getFormSyncErrors } from 'redux-form';
```

add it to your mapStateToProps which might look like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
      user: state.user, 
      metaForm: getFormMeta('register_user_form')(state),
      formSyncErrors: getFormSyncErrors('register_user_form')(state),
    };
}
```

and then you can reference in your component with `this.props.metaForm` and `this.props.formSyncErrors`

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. Perhaps I did not look or read hard enough.